# Windows Phone 8.1 change/update localization strings at run time

Tags: wpf, localization, windows-phone-8.1, runtime, globalization

I have tried to change the Resource.resx file at run time but it's impossible because during compile time all the .resx files for an app are packed into a single PRI file by the MakePRI utility and included with the app's deployment package.

For the time being I am trying to delete the ".resx" files and find another solution to create and retrieve the localization Strings files

Can you please help me by providing a solution for this problem, thank you

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you should not delete your *resw* files but leverage this feature to build your own localization mechanism.

I have recently build a tool that updates resw files (they are just XML files) at runtime and can also read them. You have to ensure that your resw files at are not compiled by PRI, for this change the build action from `PRIResource` to `Content` and select `Copy Always` to ensure that the files are available in your output directory.

Unfortunately, you can't reuse `ResXResourceReader` class which is available for Windows Form application, but you can easily write a class that is able to read and modify these entries. The format for localized data in the *resw* files is the following:

```
<data name="Name1">
    <value>this is my long string</value>
    <comment>this is a comment</comment>
</data>
```

Then you add a class that just open the expected localization files based on the user locale. And you pass the stream to the parser which will extract the localized string based on its identifier.